# Connect to TFS using windows credentials

Tags: tfs

```
NetworkCredential networkCredentials = new NetworkCredential(userName, windowsPassword, domain);

WindowsCredential windowsCredentials = new WindowsCredential(networkCredentials);
TfsClientCredentials tfsCredentials = new TfsClientCredentials(windowsCredentials);
tfsCredentials.AllowInteractive = false;

TeamProjectCollection = new TfsTeamProjectCollection(new Uri(urltoTFS), tfsCredentials);
TeamProjectCollection.Authenticate();
```

Hi,

I know the above works to connect to TFS. What I want to do is connect via my windows login, so I dont have to create a network credential object off a particular username and password.. (every example I have seen does it this way)

So basically what ever machine will run this code will use the credentials of the logged in user.

1. Can this be done,
2. If so, how do I go about it

Cheers,
John

Comment: Am I missing something? Not passing to TfsTeamProjectCollection construct the credential does not solve?

Comment: @GiulioVian what do you mean.. IF you look at code above, I can construct TfsTeamProjectCollection off TfsClientCredentials which is constucted off windows credentials which are constructed off Network Credentials.. The Network Credentials are dependent on a username and password. I do not want to use a static username/password but want to use the logged in windows credentials..

Comment: I mean: you do not need to pass credential at all, in which case the current user applies.

Comment: @GiulioVian Ah I get you now, apologies. Haha, it seems it was that simple.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to crate the correct SPN's to allow your site to get a Kerberos token to be able to pass the credentials from the Users Workstation through your website to the TFS Server. This is commonly called a "double hop issue" and is easily implemented with Active Directory.